# How to get the updated version in click once deployment

Tags: .net, clickonce

I have an application deployed with [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) .Now when i rebuild the application with some changes , and put it in the share folder from where it is installed and launch the appluication it doesnt takes the latest version instead it just launches the old version.

1. How should i check (which file) for new version.
2. is there any setting in the build file which says to check the new version.

Can somebodyy pleas help me with this??

thanks,
ashish.

Comment: The link is not accessable,it says Unable to Service Request
can you please share the content. Thanks

Comment: The link worked for me.  Also, just FYI, don't post a new answer to reply to someone.  Use the comment feature.

Answer (score 2):

You have to choose which update strategy you want to use, and configure your application as such.  There are details on this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In the Updates dialog, do you have the checkbox checked to look for updates before running the application? (Don't fill in the Update URL if it is the same as the original install URL).

Also, you need to deploy a new version -- it will not recognize it as an update if the version number is the same as the previous deployment.